# call a function without event

Tags: python

I'm new to wxpython and I hope there is a simple one-line way to solve this:
I have defined some functions:

```
def function1:
    do something
    execute function2

def function2:
    do something else
```

I want to know how I can call function2 ("execute function2") without waiting for an event. Just call function2 in the end of function1.

Edit:
Finally this works:

```
def function1():
    #do something
    self.function2()

def function2(self):
    #do something else
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call it at the end:

```py
def function1():
    # do something
    function2()

def function2():
    # do something else
```

Also, as you probably noticed, your function definitions are incorrect - you should place brackets at the end of the function name (when defining), even if it does not accept any arguments.

Comment: Yeah, I placed the brackets in my code, but forgot it in this example ;) But your answer was incorrect - this didn't worked for me. I had to add "self" as seen in my edit.

Comment: @user1654763: You hadn't mentioned that these were methods of a class. If your question is very vague (and contains typos!), of course the answer won't work out of the box.

Comment: @user1654763: David is right, functions are not exactly the same as methods of instances. Also your updated code does not work, because either the structure is completely different or `function1()` also needs `self` placed in the brackets after the name. In short, you cannot expect someone from predicting that the code in the question is completely different from the one you are using, and what the code is.

Comment: OK, thank you. I just started learning python a few days ago. I just thought there is *one* simple way to call a function =) I also have to learn more about this "self" (when it is needed and when not).

Comment: @user1654763: Actually I would say there is (more or less) _one_ way to call a function. The difference is between functions and methods - depending on what language you are coming from, in JavaScript it would be something like `this.function2()` for method and `function2()` in case of function, in PHP it would be `$this->function2()` for method and `function2()` in case of function. `self` is just a way to explicitly name a variable storing current object (such as `this` in JavaScript, `$this` in PHP). I would really recommend reading this: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596158071.do